# child actions are not allowed to perform redirect action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to use Create view with the index view to show the created item in the same page. 
For that I'm using _CreateCategory as the partial view and I added following to the index view

```
{Html.RenderAction("Create", Model);}
```

My controller's get and post methods as follows for the Create

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return PartialView("_CreateCategory",new Inventory.Models.Category());
    }

[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="Id,Description")] Category category)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Categories.Add(category);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction( "Index");
        }

        return PartialView(category);
    }
```

My index method as follows

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Categories.ToList());
    }
```

I didn't do any changes to the partial view. I'm getting error "

> child actions are not allowed to perform redirect action

. I tried many ways to overcome this. But no luck yet.

Comment: Have you decorated your method with the `[ChildActionOnly]` attribute?

Comment: No I didn't add [ChildActionOnly] attribute

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use an Ajax Form to render your create view in the index view. Initially you can render your partial create view in the index view and in your partial view you can use Ajax.BeginForm() to render the form that submit to your post create action and replace the form with returned partial view.